# How to check if link for media content (behind CORS, so no XHR Head) is stored in browser cache or not?

Tags: javascript, caching, browser, html5-audio, browser-cache

Is it possible to check whether content is stored in browser cache or not?

My case is: I have e.g. 1000 audio files and play them in random order, in case if network connection is poor I play already cached tracks and load new ones in parallel.

Browser-specific solution is not so cool but also an option.

Comment: Are you sure this should be tagged web-audio? I suspect you're looking for html5-audio? If web-audio, then you can cache the audio data youself after you decode it via the audioContext.decodeAudioData method. Just save the resulting buffer and re-use when you need it.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I cannot use Web Audio API due to CORS